# Image link and text link is seperated?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: This is the live web with pesticide extension on]
[image: This is the HTML lines]
[image: This is the css lines]

I am new at web development. I am trying to make the icon links so that when I hover over it, the icons will change colour and it works! However, when I on pesticide extensions, there is 4 boxes which are links that are separated from the image. I only want the image as links and not additional text links. any advice would be appreciated

I am expecting just the image as link and not the additional links

Comment: better post your code using code snippet rather than posting picture.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) for icons. Images with links are hard to handle. But if you use icons, you can figure it out so easily.

The first thing you have to do is include the .js to your html file. Include this code into head tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Then find the icon you want to use. I decided to use Github. So:

```
<i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
```

You can search for icons and find their codes. After that, just copy and paste.

As a result, icons acts like a text. You can add css for them like hover.

```
<a href="https://github.com"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
```